# get output from cmdline application independently of system's locale

Tags: windows, command-line, locale, i18n

I'm trying to get the full OS-version information of a w32 host in a script (thus: from the cmdline), to be run on a variety of different machines.

For this, i'm using the `systeminfo` as described in [Windows version from CMD](https://www.windows-commandline.com/find-windows-os-version-from-command/)

in theory this works great, but i discovered, that `systeminfo` will output the "keys" in the current language. e.g. (on a german w7 installation):

> Betriebssystemname: Microsoft Windows 7 Professional

this however, means that the following does not work:

```
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name:"
```

since i don't know the system-languages of the target machines, i would like to make the script language independent (rather than adding exception for "all known" languages).

can i do so?

Comment: Does wmi work on the German machines with English queries? From the command line, `wmic OS get caption` for example?

Comment: `wmic` seems works to work platfrom independently - *and* it's way faster than using `systeminfo` for single keys.